# Matching JavaScript files, but excluding mocha test files

Tags: javascript, node.js, pattern-matching

I want to find all javascript files in dir. I.e file must end with .js, but I want to exclude the ones that ends with test.js

```
const glob = require('glob');

function globbing (pattern) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    glob(pattern, function (err, files) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(files);
      }
    });
  });
}


(async () => {
  const jsFiles = await globbing('../**/*.js');
  console.log(jsFiles);
})()

outputs:
'../component/admin/userDashboard.js',
'../component/admin/userDashboard.test.js',
'../component/admin/waitingPage.js',
'../component/app.js',
'../component/app.test.js',;
```

I have tried adding !(*test.js) but test files are still included, I assume because the match the first

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't provide the function and the import. Yes I am using glob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about :

```
glob('../**/*.js', {
  ignore: '../**/*test.js', 
}, function (err, files) {
  console.log(files);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, was trying to do it within one patter. But passing extra options is a great alternative I didn't think about.